# Limit or specify the possible values of a key in an interface

Tags: typescript

I need to define an interface where the key can be one of a certain range of values.

So I have something like this

```
interface ComparisonOperator {
  [operator: string]: [string, string | number];
}
```

The key can be value like `>` `>=` `!=` ,etc

So it should be possible to build up things like:

```
{'>', ['field bla', 5]}
```

But I want to specify\limit what the possible key values can be, is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply do it like this

```
type ComparisonOperatorType = [string, string | number];

interface ComparisonOperator {
    '>': ComparisonOperatorType;
    '==': ComparisonOperatorType;
    '>=': ComparisonOperatorType;
}
```

Otherwise it is not possible as `"An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type"`